# What items can be compacted into blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft there are several items that can be placed together in a 3x3 or 2x2 block to create a "block of _____". I've seen it done with Redstone, Coal, Wheat, and Lapis. What other items can be compressed into blocks so that inventory and chest space can be reduced? I have researched many times and always end up finding one or two new items. What is the full list of compact-able items?

Comment: If anyone wants to discuss the validity or quality of this question, please do so on [meta].

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are actually quite a few number of "compactable" blocks as of [Minecraft 1.14](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_1.14).

For reference, some of these blocks are *reversible*, meaning that they can be turned back into 9 or 4 of the base material by placing them in a crafting grid or by breaking them.

Others are *non-reversible*, meaning they either cannot be turned back into their constituents at all, or else you receive less than 9 or 4.

#### Blocks crafted as 3×3 of base material

- [Block of Coal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_of_Coal) (*reversible*)
- [Block of Iron](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_of_Iron) (*reversible*)
- [Block of Gold](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_of_Gold) (*reversible*)
- [Block of Diamond](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_of_Diamond) (*reversible*)
- [Lapis Lazuli Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lapis_Lazuli_Block) (*reversible*)
- [Block of Redstone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_of_Redstone) (*reversible*)
- [Block of Emerald](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_of_Emerald) (*reversible*)
- [Hay Bales](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hay_Bale) (*block of* [Wheat](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wheat), *reversible*)
- [Melon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Melon_block) (*made of* [Melon Slices](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Melon), *not fully reversible unless broken with a [Fortune](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fortune#Fortune)-enchanted tool*)
- [Slime Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime_Block) (*reversible*)
- [Bone Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bone_Block) (*reversible*, made of Bone Meal)
- [Packed Ice](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Packed_Ice) (*not reversible*, from Ice)
- [Blue Ice](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Blue_Ice) (*not reversible*, from Packed Ice)
- [Dried Kelp Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dried_Kelp_Block) (*reversible*)
- [Hay Bale](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hay_Bale) (*reversible*, from [Wheat](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wheat))
- [Nether Wart Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Wart_Block) (*reversible*)
- [Prismarine Bricks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Prismarine) (*not reversible*, from [Prismarine Shards](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Prismarine_Shard))
- [Purpur Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Purpur_Block) (*not reversible*, made from [Popped Chorus Fruit](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Popped_Chorus_Fruit))

#### Blocks crafted as 2×2 of base material

- [Bricks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bricks) (*made of* [Bricks (item)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Brick)*, not reversible*)
- [Nether Bricks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Brick) (*made of* [Nether Bricks (item)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Brick_%28item%29)*, not reversible*)
- [Block of Clay](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clay_%28block%29) (*made of* [Clay (item)](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Clay)*, reversible when broken*)
- [Snow Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Snow) (*made of* [Snowballs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Snowball)*, reversible when broken with a shovel*)
- [Glowstone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glowstone) (*made of* [Glowstone Dust](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glowstone_Dust)*, not fully reversible unless broken with a [Fortune](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fortune#Fortune)-enchanted tool*)
- [Sandstone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sandstone) (*made of* [Sand](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sand)*, not reversible*)
- [Red Sandstone](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sandstone) (*made of* [Red Sand](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sand)*, not reversible*)
- [Wool](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wool) (*made of* [String](https://minecraft.wiki/w/String)*, not reversible*)
- [Block of Quartz](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_of_Quartz), (*made of* [Nether Quartz](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Quartz)*, not reversible*)
- [End Stone Bricks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Stone_Bricks), (*not reversible*)
- [Magma Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Magma_Block), (*made of* [Magma Cream](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Magma_Cream)*, not reversible*)
- [Prismarine](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Prismarine) (*not reversible*, from [Prismarine Shards](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Prismarine_Shard))