# How to move my base in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I live in a crappy area with no cows, sheep, villages, or anything else particularly useful. Problem is, I've been based there for a while. I have two houses (one with a mine shaft underneath it) and have chests filled with precious items. In addition, I have no idea where I'm planning on going. What's the best way for me to pack up and leave?

Comment: i would suggest breeding donkey or mules (whichever one allows you to add a chest on) and load them up, but if you have no cows, sheep or villages then it's probably a stretch to think you have even horses or donkeys

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what you consider precious. Stone, wood, dirt etc can be found anywhere.

You can put all your rare stuff (such as diamonds, gold, etc) into a [Ender Chest](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Talk:Ender_Chest).

[image: Ender Chest Image]

The Ender Chest allows you to teleport your items to wherever you build another ender chest (or just recycle the same one, read the wiki for restrictions on this).

With your stuff safely in a chest, you can explore freely without fear of death. Just keep a [bed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bed) in your inventory to update your spawn location periodically.

Comment: I don't have an Eye of Ender.

Comment: @NatanKhodorkovsky can you press t and use '/gamemode creative' just create 2 - 4 ender chests (2 if you want single chests, 4 if you want doubles) then switch back to survival

Comment: I guess. I kinda hate to cheat, though.

Comment: @NatanKhodorkovsky isn't it called Malegen in Magic The Gathering where you start off with a crpa hand and you can redraw, just in this case you had a crap hand (starting location) and just continued with it while slowly stagnating, still i get your point, it's more satisfying to go without create mode

Comment: @Memor-X Mulligan is what your referring too

Comment: @Ender yeh, i probably pissed off a bunch of Magic players by spelling it wrong *prepares for bricking*

Comment: @Memor-X If they don't want to cheat, they don't want to cheat. Just let it go.

Comment: @NatanKhodorkovsky You could go on the epic quest *without* the chest, to find a village with a priest. Just note down the coordinates of your original home so you can return (much) later. The priest will eventually trade Eyes of Ender, so you can settle near the village, gather trade goods, and eventually unlock the Eye of Ender trade. Then you can make Ender Chests and return to your home for your valuables. It'd be an adventure. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that you condense everything you have into the 'tightest' form, for instance you can turn 9 pieces of coal into a block of coal ([this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/128221/26487) has a great summary of which you can do this for).

This leaves you with an effectively much greater carrying capacity than if you took the uncondensed components. You can also reduce the amount you need to carry by leaving a 'survival stash' in your old home, just in case you find yourself back there.

You can then put things you want to transport but not have with you into an [Ender Chest](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ender_Chest) (if you can't make your own Eyes of Ender, they can be traded from villagers if you have one nearby).

If you really can't get hold of the materials for an Ender Chest you could leave your most precious materials behind while you scout ahead, constructing gradual forward bases, so when you do come to transport the valuables, you can walk a distance during the day and then hide out during the night and sleep, gradually making your spawn closer and closer to your eventual destination, wherever that may be.

A more dangerous but faster way to travel is via the Nether, where 1 meter is equivalent to 8 meters in the Overworld. There's a good [Portal Calculator](http://www.mavenspun.com/games/minecraft/) for if you've found a spot and want to sync up portals correctly. There's some good detail on the Minecraft Wiki detailing some [Nether survival techniques](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Nether_survival).

There are also some good answers on the question [What is the fastest way to travel long distances in Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20835/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-travel-long-distances-in-minecraft)

Comment: Yeah, I decided to take a similar route: I walked all the way to a village that I had previously stumbled upon, protecting myself during the night by building a large tower of cobblestone underneath myself.

Comment: @NatanK. do you mind telling me what made you change your mind about accepting my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you got an excessive amount of iron and gold from your mine maybe do this:

1. Make a map.
2. On this map, mark out the path from your current base to where you want your new home.
3. Using your excess iron and gold, build a rail network between the 2 locations.
4. Create several minecarts with chests and begin transporting your things.

Comment: Huh, if I did take that route, I would be able to easily revisit my old residence, but it would take a lot of time and effort.

Comment: @NatanKhodorkovsky it would be well worth it if you plan to invest in your world as then you can repeat the process when you make a new mine or find a new village, you just build a new smaller house nearby and have a rail network that all leads to your main house, you can make it more effective by making it underground (using glass or rock to seal up gaps) or building a skybridge that way you avoid mobs getting in the way

Comment: It isn't that I'm not willing to put time into it, but there has to be an easier way, even if i don't use console commands.

Comment: @NatanKhodorkovsky as is had been said in Zero Punctuation in the Minecraft review, Minecraft makes you work hard to get what you want before blowing it up in your fcae, you're just lucky it was at the hands of the world generator with a crap start location rather than a creaper blowing you up as you entered your house, the other way could be just to make a sky bridge between your two houses and transport everything by hand

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll try that. Before I leave, should I craft an iron golem or another utility mob? Currently, I have a full set of iron armor including a chestplate with Projectile Protection III. I also have a diamond sword (but no more diamonds), a bow, some arrows, and about 65 iron ingots.

Comment: @NatanK. if your building a sky bridge between homes then there wouldn't really be a problem with mobs if you place torches every 5-8 blocks, make the bridge out of anything you want and can get a crap load of, i normally go with wood but you can use dirt if you dont have enough, using the data you get from F3 start building the bridge in one direction until your x or y position matches your second house, then change direction until you get to your second house, since the bridge will just be i block wide and high up a utility mob would be kinds useless

Comment: @NatanK. the bridge would also serve as a starter for a rail network as when you do get time you can add rails, power rails, stations and fences so that it's safe and quicker to go between places